# No existe la función en el HTML cuando quiero agregar un script desde JavaScript

Tags: javascript

La consola me muestra el siguiente mensaje de error:

> historia.html:24 Uncaught ReferenceError: seccionPublicaciones is not defined
> at historia.html:24
> (anonymous) @ historia.html:24

Éste es el código:

```js
const seccionPublicaciones=() => {  
 for (const publicacion of publicaciones){
 let conteiner= document.createElement("div");
 conteiner.innerHTML = `<div>
 <h5>${publicacion.titulo}</h5>
 
 <p>${publicacion.parrafo}</p>
 
   
 
 </div>`
 document.getElementById('tit.parrafos').appendChild(conteiner);
  }
 }
```

```html
 <div id="tit.parrafos">
   
 </div>

<script src="menu.js"></script>
<script>
   seccionPublicaciones();
</script>
```

Comment: Deberías aclarar un poco qué quieres decir con "*cuando quiero agregar un script desde JavaScript*".

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript es un lenguaje que ejecuta el código conforme se lo encuentra y si una función no ha sido definida en el momento de llamarla, entonces genera ese error.

El problema se subsana definiendo la función antes de llamar a la función:

```html
<script>
const seccionPublicaciones = publicaciones => {  
  for (const publicacion of publicaciones) {
    let conteiner= document.createElement("div");
      conteiner.innerHTML = `
        <div>
          <h5>${publicacion.titulo}</h5>
          <p>${publicacion.parrafo}</p>
        </div>
      `;
      window["tit.parrafos"].appendChild(conteiner);
    }
  }
</script>
<div id="tit.parrafos">
</div>

<script src="menu.js"></script>
<script>
  const publicaciones = [
    { titulo: "Titulo 1", parrafo: "Párrafo 1" },
    { titulo: "Titulo 2", parrafo: "Párrafo 2" },
  ];
  seccionPublicaciones(publicaciones);
</script>
```

Debes comprobar el orden en el que cargas los archivos de JavaScript externos para organizar el orden en el que se ejecuta el código, evitando hacer uso de una función o biblioteca de funciones antes de su carga.

Además, te aconsejo que pases como parámetro la variable `publicaciones` y no sobreentiendas que ésta va a estar definida. Es un error muy común que debes evitar y que te ahorrará quebraderos de cabeza en un futuro.